# G is a graph with n vertices. Prove that $χ(G) · χ( \overline G) ≥ n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

> Let $G$ be a graph with n vertices. Prove that $\chi(G)\cdot\chi(\overline G)\geqslant n$.

I know that the chromatic number of a graph with $n$ vertices will have somewhere between $\chi(G-\ni) \leqslant\chi(G)\leqslant\ni(G-v)+1$ and also that the upperbound of the chromatic number will be greater than or equal tot he max degree of a vertex in $G+1$ and that the lower bound is the greater than or equal to the largest clique.

Is there anything we can do with this information to prove our proposition?

Comment: What is $\overline{G}$?

Comment: The complement of G

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of vertices of $G$. Take then an $a$-coloring of $G$ and a $b$-coloring of $\overline{G}$. Try to produce from that a coloring of the union of $G$ and $\overline{G}$ (and note that it is a complete graph on $n$ vertices).

Comment: Okay, so suppose we have a complete graph on $n$ vertices. Then, since every vertex is adjacent to every other vertex in the graph, we can't possibly use a color more than once. So we get a $n$-coloring on the complete graph. In a complete graph, the complement would be an independent set of $n$ vertices, each to able to be colored with just one color. Is this kind of what we want to do?

Comment: I don't understand what you have said. What we want to prove is that if we have an $a$-coloring of $G$ and a $b$-coloring of $\overline{G}$, then $ab \geq n$. This is because $\chi(G)$ is the minimal such $a$ and $\chi(\overline{G})$ is the minimal such $b$. So $\chi(G) \chi(\overline{G})$ is the minimal value of $ab$, and we want to prove that this value is never less than $n$. Moreover the complete graph on $n$ vertices comes from the union of $G$ and $\overline{G}$.

Comment: @JohnLocke Ah, I understood what you have said. No, this is not that kind of reasoning that we want to do. The goal is to prove that for every $a$-coloring of $G$ and every $b$-coloring of $\overline{G}$, we have $ab \geq n$.

Comment: I'm very lost. If you have disposable time, could you publish a proof?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to let you work a bit but I will modify my answer to include a full proof.

Comment: @JohnLocke Well, actually I will end up rewriting what is linked in the comment of ThomasGrubb. So could you say if you understand the proof linked?

Comment: Ah, just saw it. Yes I understand it now. Thank you so much!